# Insert Rows between when id falls between min and max id of that group in DB2 sql

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table and want to insert rows which falls into to range of ID columns separately for each grouped records.to achieve this i wrote  a case query on table 2 but yet not able to join and add those records.

*Table 1*

```
create table Test (
[name] varchar(10),
[value] varchar(10),
[cost] varchar(10),
[id] varchar(10),
); 

insert into Test values('bob','A','10','1');
insert into Test values('bob','G','10','7');
insert into Test values('peter','C','5','3');
insert into Test values('peter','E','5','5');
insert into Test values('John','E','7','5');
insert into Test values('John','I','7','9');

select * from  Test
```

*Table 2*

```
Table 2 
create table Test2 (
[name] varchar(10));

insert into Test2 values('A');
insert into Test2 values('B');
insert into Test2 values('C');
insert into Test2 values('D');
insert into Test2 values('E');
insert into Test2 values('F');
insert into Test2 values('G');
insert into Test2 values('H');
insert into Test2 values('I');

SELECT NAME,CASE 
WHEN NAME ='A' THEN 1
WHEN NAME ='B' THEN 2
WHEN NAME ='C' THEN 3
WHEN NAME ='D' THEN 4
WHEN NAME ='E' THEN 5
WHEN NAME ='F' THEN 6
WHEN NAME ='G' THEN 7
WHEN NAME ='H' THEN 8
WHEN NAME ='I' THEN 9 END AS ID
FROM Test2
```

OUTPUT

| name | value | cost | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | A | 10 | 1 |
| BOB | G | 10 | 7 |
| PETER | C | 5 | 3 |
| PETER | E | 5 | 5 |
| JOHN | E | 7 | 5 |
| JOHN | I | 7 | 9 |

EXPECTED RESULT

| name | value | cost | id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| BOB | A | 10 | 1 |
| BOB | B | 10 | 2 |
| BOB | C | 10 | 3 |
| BOB | D | 10 | 4 |
| BOB | E | 10 | 5 |
| BOB | F | 10 | 6 |
| BOB | G | 10 | 7 |
| PETER | C | 5 | 3 |
| PETER | D | 5 | 4 |
| PETER | E | 5 | 5 |
| JOHN | E | 7 | 5 |
| JOHN | F | 7 | 6 |
| JOHN | G | 7 | 7 |
| JOHN | H | 7 | 8 |
| JOHN | I | 7 | 9 |

Comment: Is the logic for ID that it refers to the value? Or is it entirely "random"?

Comment: yes the logic is for ID that it refers to the value, so i need to get all values in between if their id falls in that range of particular group. i am referring as group to those records whose name and cost is same.

Answer (score 0):

You may use RCTE as below.
The 1-st part of RCTE has 1 record for each group with minimum `value` + additional column with max `value` for this group.
The "cycle" in a group (in the 2-nd part of RCTE) adds a record with next letter (according to ascii order of letters in `value`) and id based on previous record and continues until this next computed letter is not greater then maximum group `value` got in the 1-st part of RCTE.

```
WITH 
  Test (name, value, cost, id) AS
(
values
  ('bob','A','10','1')
, ('bob','G','10','7')
, ('peter','C','5','3')
, ('peter','E','5','5')
, ('John','E','7','5')
, ('John','I','7','9')
)
, A (name, value, cost, id, value_max) AS
(
  select name, value, cost, int(id), value_max
  from
  (
    select 
      name, value, cost, id
    , row_number() over (partition by name, cost order by value) rn_ 
    , max(value) over (partition by name, cost) value_max
    from Test
  )
  where rn_ = 1
  
      union all
      
  select name, chr(ascii(substr(value, 1, 1)) + 1) as value, cost, id+1, value_max
  from A
  where chr(ascii(substr(value, 1, 1)) + 1) <= value_max
)
select name, value, cost, id
from A
order by name, cost;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can use a recursive CTE.  This is actually pretty simple:

```
with cte(name, value, cost, id, last_id) as (
      select name, value, cost, id, last_id
      from (select name, min(value) as value, cost, min(id) as id, max(id) as last_id
            from Test t
            group by name, cost
           ) t
      union all
      select name, chr(ascii(value) + 1), cost, id + 1, last_id
      from cte
      where id < last_id
     )
select *
from cte
order by name, value, id;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=2a91f302b0a6755d3b152c105a6e09a2) is a db<>fiddle.  Note that the Fiddle changes the types of the columns to better match the data.